# How do I limit my graph from going below zero in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I've been working on my programming project for school. The goal is to simulate ballistic trajectory including wind resistance with a graph.

I've reached my goal and just want to add some details. One detail being limiting the graph so it doesn't go below zero (since it doesn't make much sense to show the path of the projectile below ground). I want matplotlib to stop plotting the graph as soon as f(x) < 0.

However, I have no idea how to do that. I have noticed that I set the range for x by using x = np.linespace(0, 10000, 500). If the graph would go below 0 or above 10000 on the x-axis it would get cut off at 0 and/or 10000. How do I do the same thing for y?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

*bunch of variables*

x = np.linespace(0, 10000, 500)
y = *formula for ballistic trajectory*
y_0 = 0 * x 

*labels and titles*
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(0)
plt.ylim(0)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_0, color="black")
plt.show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the limits *after* the plot is created. No need to set the maximum if you do not want to.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 500)
y = 25 * x - x ** 2 

plt.grid()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(0, None) # Or similarly "plt.ylim(0)"
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: You can also set something like `plt.ylim(0, 170)` before the plot. But if you don't set the maximum, with `plt.ylim(0)`, the maximum will be set anyway, to a default value of 1. And you end up with a truncated plot. That's why you need to set it after the plot.

**Additional answer following comment**

To *remove* the data points with `y<0` instead, you can do the following:

```py
x = x[y>0]
y = y[y>0]
plt.grid()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This unfortunately does not solve the problem as the graph is still plotted below 0. plt.ylim() and plt.xlim() only moves the camera perspective so it looks like the graph doesn't go below zero. If you move around the graph with the tool provided by matplotlib, you will still see that the graph goes below zero. I want the graph to not be plotted as soon as f(x) < 0 (if that's even possible).

Comment: Then we have a different understanding of what "plotted" means. The `y<0` points do exist. If you really want to get rid of them (not sure why you would want that though), you should remove them *before* the plot. I.e. reduce the `x` and `y` numpy arrays, then plot. I updated the answer to do that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry for the little misunderstanding, English is not my native language. The reason why I don't want any negative y-values is because it doesn't make any sense to show the projectile path underground. As soon as it hits the ground, the path is finished. Whatever happens after the projectile hits the ground is not part of my project. It's like showing a graph that should visualise the death rates of people from 1900-2000 and at some point it turns into negative values.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass both the lower and the upper limit to `plt.ylim()`, the curve will only be shown where it is between those limits. Having said that, only setting the lower limit to zero as you do should at least make sure that the displayed curve does not go below zero, so I'm not sure what causes the problem.

In any case, here is a complete example that does work as intended:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 500)
y = 25 * x - x ** 2 
y_0 = 0 * x 

plt.grid()
plt.xlim(0, 30)
plt.ylim(0, 160)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_0, color="black")
```

[image: trajectory plot]